# CSS Triangle + "After" Implementation

Tags: css

I have tried to create a triangle with CSS and it looks good, however I have now got a problem implementing it after a box.

Check out my example and you will see what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/TTVuS/

It seems like the triangle after `.box` gets "cut off" and I have absolutely no idea why this happens.

I want it to look like `.arrow`.

I have tried to change dimensions of the box, the triangle etc. but nothing worked.

p.s. here is the css in case Jsfiddle is slow or not available again:

```
.box{
    background:red;
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
}

/*the triangle but its being cut off*/
.box:after{
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid green;
}

/*the triangle how it should look like*/
.arrow{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Changing the triangle to `position: absolute;` and adding `position: relative;` to the `.box` fixes it. It seems to be inheriting the height of the box.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot! Will accept the answer as soon as I can (3 mins) :)

Answer (score 4):

if you want to do [this][1]  !

insert an div class  arrow in the div class box may be the only solution.
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ouvqLa3k/

```css
html{
    padding:50px
}

.box{
    position : relative;
    background:red;
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    border : 0px;
}
/*
.box:after{
    position : relative;
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid green;
}
*/
.arrow{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="arrow">
</div>
```